# How to determine a good threshold error when checking for almost collinearity?

Tags: geometry

Let's say we have points $A$, $B$ and $C$. These points [are collinear if the area of the triangle they form is $0$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Collinear.html). So our collinearity check looks something like this:

$x_A*y_B + x_B*y_C + x_C*y_A = y_A*x_B + y_B*x_C + y_C*x_A$

This works just fine if the coordinates of our points are something like $(3,2)$, $(0,2)$ and $(-4,2)$ (as in, **exactly** on the same line):

$3*2 + 0*2 + (-4)*2 = 2*0 + 2*(-4) + 2*3$

But in other cases, we might run into rounding errors.

Let's consider the case of a regular triangle whose circumradius is $50$ and first vertex on the $x$ axis. We take its vertices to be at $(50,0)$, $(-25,43.3)$ and $(-25,-43.3)$. These are rounded values. That $43.3$ is actually more like $43.301270189221932338186158537647$, but keeping all those decimals is crazy, so we've rounded the value. Now let's consider the intersection between the first edge of this triangle (the one between the $(50,0)$ and $(-25,43.3)$ points) and the $y$ axis - this is $(0,28.9)$ (again, that $28.9$ is actually more like $28.867513459481288225457439025098$).

So these three points - $(50,0)$, $(-25,43.3)$ and $(0,28.9)$ should be almost collinear, which means our formula from above would change to something like:

$Δ = |(x_A*y_B + x_B*y_C + x_C*y_A) - (y_A*x_B + y_B*x_C + y_C*x_A)| < ε$

where $ε$ is a threshold error - anything smaller than that, and our points are close enough to being collinear.

Now the question is: ***how can we determine a good value for $ε$***?

For example, $(.00001,0)$, $(0,0)$ and $(-.00001,1.74524e-7)$ are almost collinear and so are $(1000,0)$, $(0,0)$ and $(-1000,17.4524)$ (the angle is a $179°$ one in both cases), but $Δ$ is $-1.74524e-12$ in the first case and $17452.4$ in the second case.

Comment: You must make $\Delta$ dimensionless, dividing it by a square length, for instance $AB^2+BC^2+CA^2$.

Comment: @Aretino That's computing the edges of the triangle which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid at this step (otherwise, I have the option of computing angles using the law of cosines).

Comment: @Aretino Buuut... that gives me an idea, which is to divide $Δ$ by the product between the average of the $x$ coordinates in absolute value and the average of the $y$ coordinates in absolute value. 

Comment: That might be dangerous when you have a small triangle whose vertices have large coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fix ε - like a threshold error (in a pragmatic way) then you need to create your error system to give the most favorable value smaller than the initial error.

This issue leads me to something similar in determining the values ​​of the details [this problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_detail).